# Error with my code (No File)

Tags: java

I have having problem with the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Dico {
  // Lettre à stocker
  static char lettre;
  // Dictionnaire des suffixes
  static Dico suffixe;
  // Dictionnaire des mots commençants par une lettre plus grande
  // que 'lettre' dans l'ordre alphabétique
  static Dico autreLettre;

  // Constructeur simple initialisant chacun des attributs d'un
  // objet Dico.
  private Dico(char lettre, Dico suffixe, Dico autreLettre) {
    this.lettre = lettre;
    this.suffixe = suffixe;
    this.autreLettre = autreLettre;
  }

  // Constructeur récursif construisant un dictionnaire contenant
  // un unique mot passé en argument
   Dico(String mot) {
    if (mot == null || mot.length() == 0) {
      this.lettre = '*';
      this.suffixe = null;
    } else {
      this.lettre = mot.charAt(0);
      this.suffixe = new Dico(mot.substring(1));
    }
    this.autreLettre = null;
  }
  // Méthode statique ajoutant mot au dictionnaire passé
  // en second argument
   static Dico ajouter(String mot, Dico precedent) {
    // Si le dictionnaire est vide construire un dictionnaire
    // contenant uniquement mot.
    if (precedent == null) {
      return new Dico(mot);
    }
    // Si mot null ne pas modifier le dictionnaire
    if(mot == null) {
      return precedent;
    }
    // Si longueur du mot nulle et '*' déjà à cet endroit
    // ne pas modifier le dictionnaire ('*' plus petit que
    // toutes les lettres dans l'ordre < ), sinon ajouter '*'
    // avant toutes les autres lettres contenu dans le dictionnaire
    // précédent.
    if(mot.length() == 0) {
      if (precedent.lettre == '*') {
        return precedent;
      } else {
        return new Dico('*',null,precedent);
      }
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot est plus petite que toutes les premières
    // lettres des autres mots du dictionnaire ajouter le mot avant tous 
    // les autres mots.
    if (precedent.lettre > mot.charAt(0)) {
      Dico temp = new Dico(mot);
      temp.autreLettre = precedent;
      return temp;
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot est plus grande que la première lettre
    // du dictionnaire, ajouter le mot au dictionnaire des mots commençants
    // par d'autres lettres
    if (precedent.lettre < mot.charAt(0)) {
      precedent.autreLettre = ajouter(mot,precedent.autreLettre);
      return precedent;
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot est déjà dans le dictionnaire, 
    // ajouter le suffie du mot au dictionnaire des suffixes de cette lettre.
    precedent.suffixe = ajouter(mot.substring(1),precedent.suffixe);
    return precedent;
  }

  // Méthode de recherche du mot dans le dictionnaire.
   static boolean rechercher(String mot) {
    // Si le mot ou le dictionnaire sont vide retourner faux
    if (mot == null) {
      return false;
    }
    // Si la longueur du mot est nulle, retourner vrai si 
    // la lettre courante est '*', sinon retourner faux.
    if (mot.length() == 0){
      return (lettre == '*');
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot est plus petite que la 
    // première lettre de tous les mots du dictionnaire le 
    // mot n'est pas dans le dictionnaire.
    if (lettre > mot.charAt(0)) {
      return false;
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot est plus grande que la lettre courante,
    // rechercher le mot dans le dictionnaire des mots commençants par une autre lettre
    if (lettre < mot.charAt(0)) {
      return autreLettre.rechercher(mot);
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot est la lettre courante, rechercher le suffixe du mot 
    // dans le dictionnaire.
    return suffixe.rechercher(mot.substring(1));
  }
  public // Méthode utilisée par println() pour afficher le dictionnaire. 
  // Appelle l'autre méthode toString avec un suffixe vide.
   String toString(){
    return this.toString("");
  }
  // Méthode utilisée pour afficher le dictionnaire.
   String toString(String prefix){
    String tmp = "";
    if (lettre == '*'){
      // Si '*' est la lettre courante le préfixe est un mot du dictionnaire,
      // le stocker pour l'affichage suivi du caractère '\n' (retour à la ligne).
      tmp = prefix + "\n";
    } else {
      // Sinon ajouter la lettre courante au préfixe pour afficher le dictionnaire des
      // suffixes.
      tmp = suffixe.toString(prefix+lettre);
    }
    // Si le dictionnaire des mots commençants par une autre lettre n'est pas vide
    // l'afficher.
    if(autreLettre != null) {
      tmp += autreLettre.toString(prefix);
    }
    return tmp;
  }

  // Méthode statique qui retire un mot du dictionnaire passé en argument 
   static Dico retirer(String mot, Dico precedent){
    if (mot == null) {
      return precedent;
    }
    if (precedent == null) {
      return null;
    }
    // Si mot vide retirer '*'
    if (mot.length() == 0) {
      if (precedent.lettre == '*') {
        return precedent.autreLettre;
      } else {
        return precedent;
      }
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot plus petite que la lettre courante,
    // le mot n'est pas dans le dictionnaire, retourner le dictionnaire 
    // inchangé.
    if (precedent.lettre > mot.charAt(0)) {
      return precedent;
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot est supérieure à la lettre courante,
    // mettre à jour le dictionnaire des mots commençants par une autre 
    // lettre
    if (precedent.lettre < mot.charAt(0)) {
      precedent.autreLettre = retirer(mot,precedent.autreLettre);
      return precedent;
    }
    // Si la première lettre du mot est égale à la lettre courante, 
    // mettre à jour le dictionnaire des suffixe en retirant le suffixe du mot.
    // Si le dictionnaire des suffixe est non vide retourner le dictionnaire 
    // précédent mis à jour sinon, il n'y plus de mot dans le dictionnaire commençant 
    // par la lettre courante elle est donc éliminée en retournant le dictionnaire des 
    // mots commençants par une autre lettre. 
    precedent.suffixe = retirer(mot.substring(1),precedent.suffixe);
    if(precedent.suffixe==null) {
      return precedent.autreLettre;
    }
    return precedent;
  }

  // Vérificateur orthographique qui lit l'ensemble des mots du dictionnaire dans un fichier
  // passé en premier argument et vérifie que les mots du fichier passé en second argument font 
  // partie du dictionnaire.
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
   if(args.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: java Dico <dico> <fichier>");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Dico d = null;
    FileReader dico = new FileReader(args[0]);
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(dico);
    st.ordinaryChar('.');
    while (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
      if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD)
        d = ajouter(st.sval,d);
    }
    FileReader fichier = new FileReader(args[1]);
    st = new StreamTokenizer(fichier);
    st.ordinaryChar('.');
    while (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
      if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD)
          if(!rechercher(st.sval)){
          System.out.println(st.sval);};
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the error message:
Usage: java Dico

every time i run the program it's reach this code of line

```
if(args.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: java Dico <dico> <fichier>");
      System.exit(1);
    }
```

and give me this error message:
Usage: java Dico

the only problem that's still is the file ,how to upload the file to the program so i can work with it because obviously the file it's empty or there is no file to work with, that's why i am having this error line of code any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pass exactly one argument to your app. Like: ``Dico myFile.txt``

Comment: your problem is that you specify that only one argument is to be supplied to your code, in the main method. However in your other code snippet you specify two arguments must be supplied. Please clarify the correct number of arguments for the program.

Comment: The code you posted does not have a `if(args.length != 2) {` anywhere. Instead it has `if(args.length != 1) {`. Please make sure the code you run and post is the same. If you make experimental changes afterwards without updating the question, it will be very confusing.

Comment: Jean Logeart where should i pass this argument thanks.

Comment: Davis Broda ,that other guy ,so sorry it's 2 in the argument ,i've Fixed it.

Comment: Any One can help me here thanks